# How to stop loading Selenium chromeDriver if it loads for more than 10 sec?

Tags: selenium, load, selenium-chromedriver

Is there any way to set a property for ChromeDriver to stop loading if time exceeds 10 seconds?

Something like the following pseudocode:

```
WebDriver dr = new ChromeDriver();
dr.loadLimit(10 SECONDS);
```

PS `implicit wait` is not going to work because it waits for Chrome response and only then starts counting 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 2.1 of selenium chromedriver it supports a page load timeout. Before that version it was missing. (See the discussion about this [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=9))

This is how you would set this in Java:

```
int pageLoadTimeout = 10;
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(pageLoadTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

(see the [webdriver spec](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webdriver/raw-file/default/webdriver-spec.html#timeouts) and the [selenium resources about this](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html))

Answer (score 3):

In Python: `driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)`

Answer (score 1):

It work for me

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time

desired_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
desired_capabilities['pageLoadStrategy'] = 'none'

d = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=spider.desired_capabilities)
d.get('http://www.google.com')
time.sleep(10)
```